# Clojure Spec - Register a spec pointing at another spec

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

Could someone shed a light on the following behavior please?

Let's assume I have this namespace with a spec:

```clj
(ns user.specs
  (:require [clojure.alpha.spec :as s]
            [clojure.alpha.spec.gen :as gen]
            [clojure.string :as str]))


# Non-blank string of 20 to 50 ascii chars.
(s/def ::text (s/with-gen
                (s/and string? #(not (str/blank? %)))
                #(gen/such-that
                   (complement str/blank?)
                   (gen/fmap
                     clojure.string/join
                     (gen/vector
                       (gen/char)
                       20 50)))))
```

Now I want to reuse this spec.

```clj
(in-ns 'user)

(require '[user.specs :as su])
=> nil

(def kws [::dir
          ::ns])
=> #'user/kws

(s/def ::dir ::su/text)
=> :user/dir

(s/def ::ns string?)
=> :user/ns

(s/register ::spec (s/schema* kws))
=> :user/spec
```

When exercising the last spec, I get an error:

```clj
(s/exercise ::spec)
Error printing return value (IllegalArgumentException) at clojure.core/-cache-protocol-fn (core_deftype.clj:583).
No implementation of method: :conform* of protocol: #'clojure.alpha.spec.protocols/Spec found for class: clojure.lang.Keyword
```

However, if I redef the `::dir` spec usinig `s/register` and `s/get-spec` instead of `s/def`, no problem:

```clj
(s/register ::dir (s/get-spec ::su/text))
=> :user/dir

(s/exercise ::spec)
=>
([#:user{:dir "teôÆ>EÃ¼áéNj¬u}zþs²DÍ$", :ns ""}
  #:user{:dir "teôÆ>EÃ¼áéNj¬u}zþs²DÍ$", :ns ""}]
 [#:user{:dir ":éû,@Î|)Q«óCS\t´ÿ4ÚÝÜº»Ân5Zq", :ns ""}
  #:user{:dir ":éû,@Î|)Q«óCS\t´ÿ4ÚÝÜº»Ân5Zq", :ns ""}]
... elided
```

I'm assuming, from the error message, that with `s/def`, spec resolves `::dir` as the literal `::su/text` keyword instead of the associated spec.

1) Why?
2) Is `s/register` + `s/get-spec` an appropriate solution?

I'm trying to reuse a "utility" spec in a few places under domain specific names.

FWIW, I'm using spec-alpha2 in order to build specs dynamically and benefit from `schema` + `select`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aliasing specs like `(s/def ::dir ::su/text)` is not currently working in spec 2, which is still a work in progress.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Thanks!